# write a csv cell by cell using python

Tags: python-2.7, csv

Is it possible to write a csv cell by mentioning its row and column number. I'm aware of python 'csv' module in which 'csv.writer' has only writerow and writerows method to write data. These methods always writes the data in a new row, but i want to write it in a single row different columns in one run. Problem is i cant accumulate data in a list and write it at once, I have to do some action and get data, to write it to the next column

For example
I have to open csv and start with a new row, write some data in the first column, perform some action get the data and write it to the second column, likewise i have to write many columns

As mentioned above I've tried it using csv.writer's **writerow** and **writecolumn** methods and couldn't accomplish this. Anyone had come across similar thing, kindly let me know how can i accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you are filling columns one by one, from left to right - use normal
`file.write()`, separated by coma :)

example:

```
f = open('test.csv', 'w')
f.write('ab,')

# do something

#write data to next column
f.write('ab,')
```

It will produce test.csv with first row:
`ab,ab`

Comment: and what about writing to a different row?

Comment: Well, in csv next row is simply next line in file. But if you want to do more complex works on csv's, I'd suggest you to try https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html